# Tomcat: TLSv1.2 with strong ciphers not working

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jsse

I installed Tomcat-7, **configured support for TLSv1.2** on port 8443. 
My Connector configuration: 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"

I then configured a list of strong ciphers I wanted to use.
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

As I have read, Tomcat can either use Java JSSE or OpenSSL 
JSSE    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
OpenSSL protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" 
My tomcat connector is configured with JSSE protocol.

It works if I add the following ciphers with SHA1. (No GCM with SHA1)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

I have downloaded the Java cryptographic extensions policy files. 
Tried with both Java 7 and Java 8.

Before I installed the Cryptographic Extensions I got the following error while starting up Tomcat

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
mai 20, 2014 3:57:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory     getEnableableCiphers
WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine :     TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
```

According to Java 7 Documentation all these strong ciphers with GCM-SHA384 and CBC-SHA384 should be supported:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites

If I change the ciphers just a little bit:

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
mai 20, 2014 4:21:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getEnableableCiphers
WARNING: None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA584,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA584,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA584,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA584
```

That would indicate that that my list of ciphers are supported by my Tomcat/Java.

Could the problem be with the Browser? I have tried the latest Chromium and Firefox. After checking some commits I found out that Chromium does support SHA256, SHA384 and AES-GCM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that neither Chromium nor Firefox support these higher ciphers. 
The strongest/highest cipher available is TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
No support for SHA384 and no AES_256_GCM

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html 
Cipher Suites (in order of preference) 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f) 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e) 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a) 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014) 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007) 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011) 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33) 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x32) 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5) 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)

Comment: For Firefox 37.0.2, the list is:

Answer (score 2):

The [standard algorithm name documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites) you're quoting is just the list of names, which are effectively reserved, but not necessarily implemented.

The [SunJSSE provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) (the default JSSE provider in the Oracle JRE) doesn't implement any GCM cipher suite in Java 7. They are in the [updated table for the Java 8 implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider).

You might also need `sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"`.

Comment: Already have sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" and sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
It seems these ciphers are implemented in Java 7, but only for use with TLSv1.2
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

The ciphers with GCM looks to be implemented in Java 8.

Comment: I have tried running with both Java 7 and Java 8.
Opening in browser https://localhost:8443 gives the following error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: According to the Java 7 documentation I should be able to use CBC-SHA384, but that is not the case as only SHA1 is available. Running Tomcat with Java 8 is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am a web developer and facing the similar issue running the application with Tomcat 7 and Java7 versions and found the fix.

by adding the below property in the server.xml file of tomcat in

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox 37.0.2, the list of supported ciphers is:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)
```