# Ciphers Configuration in server.xml

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, tls1.2, server.xml

I configured server.xml like below:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" clientAuth="false" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" keystoreFile="conf/server.p12" keystorePass="${xxxx.keystorePass}" keystoreType="PKCS12" maxHttpHeaderSize="65535" maxParameterCount="-1" maxPostSize="-1" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="SSL" port="8443" scheme="https" secure="true" server="XXXX" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But my application is not started. Why the ciphers I configured are not accepted during tls handshake?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Tomcat? Which version? 'native' (=APR=OpenSSL) or JSSE? If th latter, which Java? What browser(s)? With either OpenSSL or JSSE, ciphersuite mismatch would not cause that error, it would cause a specific error like 'CIPHER_MISMATCH' or ''NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP', so your problem is probably other. If JSSE, sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` is a quick way to get debugging data; on either you can use an external capture like tcpdump or wireshark, or try to connect with `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -msg` (below 1.1.1 _might_ need `-servername $host`).

Comment: Java version 8, firefox browser(recently updated and also checked with chrome). Also checked with `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -msg`, it gives `CONNECTED(0000020C)` with additional info.But I dont know why it is not connecting in the browser.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The problem arises only when I configure the ciphers not listed by firefox and chrome. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762762/tomcat-tlsv1-2-with-strong-ciphers-not-working?rq=1) Brad Knowles's comment

Comment: Okay, I see your point, both Firefox and Chrome for some reason skip CBC+SHA2 ciphers while they both support GCM+SHA2 and CBC+SHA1 (although the FF78esr that I just got autoupdated to rejects protocols below TLS1.2). But I repeat _that_ gives different errors than you show, which means you have an additional problem somewhere. And since it occurs before ciphersuite agreement which is essentially the first thing in SSL/TLS handshake, I'll bet it has to do with a proxy; that would also explain an `openssl s_client` difference, because `openssl` doesn't use any proxy options.

Comment: PS: note in `openssl s_client` `CONNECTED(number)` is only the _TCP_ connection; the _SSL/TLS_ connection (handshake) is detailed in what you call additional info and could very well have failed for all you know.